# Using jenkins variables in Pipelane plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

sorry for bad English

i`m trying to use my jenkins BuildNumber in my pipelane, but jenkins dont use it.

My pipe:

```
node {
 stage ('Build')
  {
 bat '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/msbuild.exe" D:/rbp-maintenance/_buildscripts/Targets.proj /p:BuildNumber=${env.BUILD_NUMBER} /p:SolutionName=Maintenance.sln'
  }     
}
```

In the console i have some text:

```
D:\rbp-maintenance>"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/msbuild.exe" D:/rbp-maintenance/_buildscripts/Targets.proj /p:BuildNumber=${env.BUILD_NUMBER} /p:SolutionName=Maintenance.sln
```

Also i`m try to use 
    env.BUILD_NUMBER
    env.$BUILD_NUMBER

What i`m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes to enable [string interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation)

```
bat "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/msbuild.exe\" D:/rbp-maintenance/_buildscripts/Targets.proj /p:BuildNumber=${env.BUILD_NUMBER} /p:SolutionName=Maintenance.sln"
```